# warning: 'set' may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

Tags: c

how can i solve this warning?

Code:

```
void socket_dontroute(socket_t s)
{
    int set;
    if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_DONTROUTE, (const char *) &set, sizeof(int)) < 0) {
        sys_err("setsockopt: dontroute: %s", strerror(errno));
        socket_close(s);
        return;
    }
}
```

int set; I know it's because of the statement, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: How about `int set = 0;` Also setsockopt expects a `const void *` for option_name.

Comment: Or probably `int set = 1;` since the docs say `For setsockopt(), the argument should be nonzero to enable a boolean option, or zero if the option is to be disabled.` and it sounds as if you want to enable that option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing `set` as a pointer to `setsockopt`, but are only declaring the variable and not initializing it. That means that the content of set could be anything that is present at its memory address, and the compiler is warning you of it. As the comments rightfully stated, choose a value for set according to your functions requirement.